# Can I recover Python objects when Jupyter kernel suddenly died?

Tags: python, jupyter

I was running a machine learning script in Python. After 30 hrs of run until model training, at the next code during prediction, the kernel died according to prompt of Jupyter notebook.

When I hit "OK", I continued the run on next cells, but the objects were lost! Like, it came out as an error saying "name_of_my_object is undefined". Even the functions from imported modules were lost...and everything need to be ran to work again.

Do I really have no choice but to re-run the whole thing again?

I tried the revert to last checkpoint, I don't know how that specifically helps. When I did, it's still the same, no objects and no modules were working.

Comment: Answer is almost certainly "No". The objects are tied to a specific process; if that process dies, they're gone.

Comment: You should really save your models to disk after training if it takes this long for a single run. That way, if the kernel dies you can simply load the model and use it.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Your exact script to load checkpoint will depend on your library used.

For example in pytorch:

```
with open(os.path.join(output, "log.csv"), "a") as f:
    epoch_resume = 0
    bestLoss = float("inf")
    try:
        # Attempt to load checkpoint
        checkpoint = torch.load(os.path.join(output, "checkpoint.pt"))
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
        optim.load_state_dict(checkpoint['opt_dict'])
        scheduler.load_state_dict(checkpoint['scheduler_dict'])
        epoch_resume = checkpoint["epoch"] + 1
        bestLoss = checkpoint["best_loss"]
        f.write("Resuming from epoch {}\n".format(epoch_resume))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        f.write("Starting run from scratch\n")

    for epoch in range(epoch_resume, num_epochs):
        print("Epoch #{}".format(epoch), flush=True)
        # your model training code
                    # Save checkpoint
        save = {
            'epoch': epoch,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'best_loss': bestLoss,
            'loss': loss,
            'opt_dict': optim.state_dict(),
            'scheduler_dict': scheduler.state_dict(),
        }
        torch.save(save, os.path.join(output, "checkpoint.pt"))
        if loss < bestLoss:
            torch.save(save, os.path.join(output, "best.pt"))
            bestLoss = loss
```